# How to install Grafana on Mac

Tags: grafana

I tied the following steps

> cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/grafana/grafana
>   go run build.go setup
>   I got the following 
>       Version: 2.5.0-pre1, Linux Version: 2.5.0, Package Iteration: pre1
>       go get -v github.com/tools/godep
>       github.com/tools/godep (download)
>       github.com/tools/godep/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/kr/fs
>       github.com/tools/godep/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/pmezard/go-difflib/difflib
>       github.com/tools/godep/Godeps/_workspace/src/golang.org/x/tools/go/vcs
>       github.com/tools/godep
>       go get -v github.com/blang/semver
>       github.com/blang/semver (download)
>       github.com/blang/semver
>       go get -v github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3
>       go install -v github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3

then i executed

> $GOPATH/bin/godep restore
>   i got no putput but command got executed

then i ran the command

> go run build.go build

```
Version: 2.5.0-pre1, Linux Version: 2.5.0, Package Iteration: pre1
rm -r bin
rm -r Godeps/_workspace/pkg
rm -r Godeps/_workspace/bin
rm -r dist
rm -r tmp
rm -r /Users/skhare/sk/go/pkg/darwin_amd64/github.com/grafana
rm -r ./bin/grafana-server
rm -r ./bin/grafana-server.md5
 GOPATH=/Users/skhare/sk/go/src/github.com/grafana/grafana/Godeps/_workspace:/Users/skhare/sk/go
go build -ldflags -w -X main.version '2.5.0-pre1' -X main.commit 'v2.1.2+394-    gfb767f5' -X main.buildstamp 1442671169 -o ./bin/grafana-server .
# github.com/grafana/grafana
link: warning: option -X main.version 2.5.0-pre1 may not work in future releases; use -X main.version=2.5.0-pre1
link: warning: option -X main.commit v2.1.2+394-gfb767f5 may not work in future releases; use -X main.commit=v2.1.2+394-gfb767f5
link: warning: option -X main.buildstamp 1442671169 may not work in future releases; use -X main.buildstamp=1442671169
```

then i executed

> npm install

i had to install npm

```
>npm install -g grunt-cli
/usr/local/bin/grunt -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt
grunt-cli@0.1.13 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli
├── resolve@0.3.1
├── nopt@1.0.10 (abbrev@1.0.7)
└── findup-sync@0.1.3 (lodash@2.4.2, glob@3.2.11)

>grunt

Running "jscs:src" (jscs) task
>> 156 files without code style errors.

Running "jshint:source" (jshint) task

✔ No problems


Running "jshint:tests" (jshint) task

✔ No problems


Running "tslint:source" (tslint) task
>> 11 files lint free.

Running "clean:gen" (clean) task
Cleaning public_gen...OK

Running "copy:public_to_gen" (copy) task
Created 122 directories, copied 553 files

Running "less:src" (less) task
File public_gen/css/bootstrap.dark.min.css created.
File public_gen/css/bootstrap.light.min.css created.
File public_gen/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css created.

Running "concat:cssDark" (concat) task
File public_gen/css/grafana.dark.min.css created.

Running "concat:cssLight" (concat) task
File public_gen/css/grafana.light.min.css created.

Running "typescript:build" (typescript) task
42 files created. js: 14 files, map: 14 files, declaration: 14 files (968ms)

Done, without errors.

>go get github.com/Unknwon/bra
```

the above command did not give any output, nor an error message

> bra run
>   it says -bash: bra: command not found

i tried to look for the resolution, but i could not find it. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Recompile backend on source change
To rebuild on source change (requires that you executed godep restore)

```
go get github.com/Unknwon/bra
bra run
```

Running Grafana Locally
You can run a local instance of Grafana by running:

```
 ./bin/grafana-server
```

You must have missed this step!

```
 go get github.com/Unknwon/bra
```

Comment: i did xecute the command go get github.com/Unknwon/bra, but it did not give me any output on screen neither an error message, but i got the shell prompt after executing this command. I have mentioned above also about this command.

Comment: I tried this command >sudo go get github.com/Unknwon/bra.  I got the following message "package github.com/Unknwon/bra: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath". I dont know what changes i have to do.

Comment: I did not set the GOPATH and GOROOT in .bashrc, finally  able to execute everything without error.

Comment: Is goroot required. I am having the same problem. Could you explain what you did

Answer (score 1):

You can install Grafana using home brew.

```
brew update
brew install grafana
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue where Go is just being installed to build something else (for me, it was Grafana). In which case $GOPATH/bin is not in your PATH. $GOPATH/bin/bra should work. It did for me.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you installing Grafana inside Docker. If you install [Docker for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/), the GUI ([Kitematic](https://kitematic.com/)) will allow you to install grafana as easily as one click. You will just need to create a new container with "+ New" button, search grafana through the exisiting image lists and click "Create"

[image]

Docker will download grafana and it will appear in the left sidebar:

[image]